# VBA - Check selected checkboxes against sheet range

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying for some time to do the following:

1. Check which checkboxes/weight in Userform are selected.
2. Compare checkboxes captions/weight against range.
3. If checkboxes captions/weight in range: do nothing.
4. If checkboxes captions/weight not in range: delete values in range that DO NOT match currently selected checkboxes.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? I've though about dictionaries or arrays as you can see in the ilustration above, but I have no idea how to implement these things. My VBA skills are very rudimental still. Please let me know if something doesn't make sense, I'll be happy to help!

This is the range (range size may vary).

[image: This is the range!]

These are the metrics (in the Userform):

[image]

Dictionary is working well:

```
Dim dict As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim mBox As CheckBox, wBox As TextBox

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.RemoveAll

For i = 1 To 12
    Set mBox = frmSeg.Controls("seg_cb_" & i)
    Set wBox = frmSeg.Controls("seg_tb_W_" & i)
    
    If cBox.Value = True Then
        dict.Add Key:=mBox.Caption, Item:=wBox.Value
    End If
Next i
```

Attempt at deleting the values (not working):

```
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    j = 15
        If dict.Keys()(i) <> Sheets("HCP_UI").Cells(j, 9) And dict.Items()(i) <> Sheets("HCP_UI").Cells(j, 10) Then
            Sheets("HCP_UI").Range(Cells(j, 9), Cells(j, 10)).Delete
            
        End If
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Do you actually want to delete rows? Or just clear the values in the cells? Or do you want a filter to hide non-conforming rows? I

Comment: I want to clear the values in the cells. Sorry for not being clear!

Comment: Tie the checkboxes to actual cells in your worksheet. Those cells will then display TRUE/FALSE (checked/un-checked). Then write formulas based on which are selected to determine if the value is in range, so in an adjacent column or off to the side. Then loop that range and delete anything in the corresponding value range that does not match.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman but then the weights will not be considered. Or am I misunderstanding something? :)

Comment: @soraia635 - you can write you formula to check each weight, if it is in the range selected by the user. The point is that everything can be driven by formula - maybe more than one is needed - if set up correctly. And the code can just wipe out what is no longer relevant based on the formula result. Imagine a column next to the weight column titled `inRange`. That formula is something like: `AND(weight>=A,weight<=B)`. You can drag this formula down the rows. Any weight where the result is false can be removed.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman can you please check my answer? Do you happen to know if it's possible to have keys with more than 1 item (dictionaries)?

Comment: @soraia635 - you can have a key that holds another dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working pretty well for me:

```
' Delete entire range
Dim uSheet As Worksheet
Dim dict As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim mBox As CheckBox, wBox As TextBox
Dim key1 As String
Dim item1 As String
Dim item2 As Long
Dim aKey As Variant

Set nmMetric = New Collection
Set uSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HCP_UI")

' Delete old values in Tmetrics + Weights

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

dict.RemoveAll

For i = 1 To 9
    If frmSeg.Controls("seg_cb_" & i).Value = True And frmSeg.Controls("seg_ob_T_" & i) = True Then
        dict.Add Key:=frmSeg.Controls("seg_cb_" & i).Caption, Item:=frmSeg.Controls("seg_tb_W_" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

uSheet.Range("I3:J" & uSheet.Range("J" & uSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Clear

j = 3
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    uSheet.Cells(j, 9) = dict.Keys()(i)
    uSheet.Cells(j, 10) = dict.Items()(i)
    
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

However for a different case, I'd need my dictionary to have keys with 2 items. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in dictionaries with more than 1 item: Class modules + dictionaries works!

Check this [link](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/#Example_3_8211_Summing_Multiple_Values), it's where I found my answer!